# SQL return 4 columns including only the maximum and minimum salary for each department labeled as "highest salary" and "lowest salary" using CASE

Tags: sql, case, correlated-subquery

This is embarrassing, and I've been debating whether or not to even bother you guys with this.  Every aspect of this post is going to show what a complete newbie I am to this so please accept my profuse apologies in advance.  I'm learning sql and for the last few days I've been trying to solve this homework problem.  I'm supposed to write a query using a correlated subquery and CASE conditional expressions to return 4 columns from my "employee" table: department, first_name, salary and under the last column "salary_in_department" whether the salary is the "HIGHEST SALARY" or the "LOWEST SALARY".  So I'm supposed to only return two salaries for each department, just the HIGHEST SALARY and the LOWEST SALARY.

I have been changing this and that part of my query, getting either errors each time or all the salaries for every department all returned as HIGHEST SALARY in the 4th column of "salary_in_department".  I've searched everything I can think of online from "sql how to query both min and max salary for each department in same select statement" to "sql subquery alias error" to "sql min and max salary for each department" to "sql min and max salary using CASE" to "sql min and max salary for each department using subqueries", etc.

This is my latest attempt:

SELECT department, first_name, salary, a.salary_in_department

FROM (SELECT department, first_name, salary,

CASE WHEN salary = MIN(salary) THEN 'LOWEST SALARY'

WHEN salary = MAX(salary) THEN 'HIGHEST SALARY'

END as salary_in_department

FROM employees

GROUP BY department, first_name, salary) a

GROUP BY department, first_name, salary, salary_in_department

ORDER BY department

Any suggestions on how to go about it or how to research it better on my own so I don't have to bug people here with basic questions please?  Or if I'm making posting faux-pas please point those out also.  Among all the answers here on stackoverflow to my google searches I haven't been able to adapt the bits and pieces to my particular situation.

Comment: Please post code as text rather than an image.

Comment: Thank you.  I wanted to show the result also, but I'll change it right now.  Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Do a min and a max on the table, grouped by department and then join by department and salary:

```
declare @table table (
department varchar(20),
name varchar(20),
salary decimal(20,2))

insert into @table select 'Finance', 'Jim', 120000
insert into @table select 'Finance', 'John', 80000
insert into @table select 'IT', 'Doug', 200000
insert into @table select 'IT', 'Jane', 250000
insert into @table select 'IT', 'Mike', 50000
insert into @table select 'IT', 'Mary', 55000


select
    t.department,
    t.name,
    t.salary,
    case
        when not maxTbl.MaxItem is null then 'Highest Salary' 
        else 
            case when not minTbl.MinItem is null then 'Lowest Salary' else '' end end as [Salary In Department]
from 
    @table t
    left join (select department, Max(salary) as MaxItem from @table group by department) maxTbl on t.department = maxTbl.department and t.salary = maxTbl.MaxItem
    left join (select department, Min(salary) as MinItem from @table group by department) minTbl on t.department = minTbl.department and t.salary = minTbl.MinItem
```

[image: SQL Results]

Comment: Thank you, Josh.  I'll study how you did it.